# How to break words on an input field so it starts a new line once the width of the field is reached?

Tags: html, css, forms, input, line-breaks

```css
.form-container {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.form-container input[type=text] {
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
    <form class="form-container">
      First name:<br>
      <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
      <br>
      Last name:<br>
      <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
      <br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

I need to use an input field, and not a textarea, and I would like the words to break once the width of the input field is reached. At the moment all is written in the same line.

Find below the code that I've been trying.

Thanks in advance for helping this newbie!

```
.form-container {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.form-container input[type=text] {
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```
    <form class="form-container">
      First name:<br>
      <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
      <br>
      Last name:<br>
      <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
      <br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

Comment: you cannot, textarea are made for that purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const mickey = document.querySelector('#firstname').textContent;
```

```css
.form-container {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

#firstname {
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  max-width: 60px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
    <form class="form-container">
      First name:<br>
      <div id="firstname" contenteditable="true">Mickey</div>
      <br>
      Last name:<br>
      <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
      <br><br>
      <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="console.log(mickey);">
    </form>
```

You can't do that to an input text field, but a contenteditable div can surely help. But be careful when making something which takes up the value from div as it makes some unintented consequences. I tried returning the value from div but it won't return the real value, so here, you are on your own!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "break" exactly, but if you mean break onto a separate line, you can't have multi-line text input field, as far as I know.

You could, with some javascript, mirror the value in the input field in a div tag, which could wrap the text...

Comment: do you have any example of this?

Answer (score 0):

In order to break text flow to the next line in an input, the input tag becomes useless, the  tag was made specifically for this.